# Как выполнить скрипт JS в зависимости от ширины окна браузера?

Tags: javascript

Делаю так:

```
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (x <='950') {
$('#search_mob').append( $('#search') ); 
}
```

Или так:

```
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (document.documentElement.clientHeight <='950') {
$('#search_mob').append( $('#search') ); 
}
```

И у меня ничего не выходит...((

Comment: А зачем вы сравниваете число со строкой?

Comment: Разрешения или расширения окна? Или расширение это для вас синоним для ширина?

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (x <= 950) {
  $('#search_mob').append( $('#search') ); 
}
```

Кажись все заработало, с таким кодом как выше...
оказывается допустил элементарную ошибку, вместо clientWidth было clientHeight

Comment: Мне остаётся непонятно, зачем вы число сравниваете со строкой

Comment: Честно, я не знаю) '950' это строка, и его нужно в число преобразовать?

Comment: Да, просто кавычки уберите и будет число. Конечно, в js оно и так и этак работает, но сравнение разных типов обычно считается плохим кодом

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На чистом JS реализуется примерно следующим образом.

```js
function someFunc() {
  // Выполняем действие, если ширина меньше 1000px
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  if (w < 1000) {
    console.log("Че-то делаем");
  }
}

// Выполняем заново при изменении размера окна
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  console.log("Размер окна изменен");
  someFunc();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var widthB = $('body').width();
if(widthB <= 950){пишешь тут код}
```

Comment: Не факт что поможет

Comment: @andreymal 100% поможет

Comment: Нет, вдруг тупо элемента search_mob не существует или код запихнут в функцию которая не вызывается?)

Comment: С таким макаром и его функция может не заработать и вообще любая, выучи JS )

Comment: Именно поэтому нужно было задать уточняющие вопросы, прежде чем писать ответ, который не факт что поможет. JS я знаю девять лет.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю что это не то, о чем спрашивал автор, но тем не менее я предполагаю что задача состоит в показать/скрыть элемент в зависимости от ширины окна. Если так, то я искренне уверен, что такая задача должна быть решена средствами [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) а не `JS`

Что-то вроде

```
@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
  #search {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё ерунда на самом деле.

Если вопрос про адаптацию верстки для разных устройств, я бы использовал крохотную библиотеку: http://matthewhudson.me/projects/device.js/ , обычно подключаю ей "инлайново" в хедере и использую без проблем.

Если же четко про ширину экрана, то есть занятная штука как [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)